# Issue flattening Excel Files to a new folder using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code. Currently this code will loop through a folder of excel files and will open them and then save them in that folder, but I can't get the code to then take those files flatten them and then place them into another folder. Any advice?

```
Sub ALoopFile()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim SendTo As String
Dim SendFile As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook 'Workbook Stores Workbook

MyFolder = "Y:\Dropbox (Efficiency3)\Monthly Projects\001 - AU"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")

SendTo = "Y:\Dropbox (Efficiency3)\Monthly Projects\001 - AU\Flattened_Files"
SendFile = Dir(SendTo & "\*.xls")
Do While MyFile <> ""


Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=3) 'Sets CurrentWB = to that long name. This becomes the name of the workbook.
    CurrentWB.RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen 'Enables Macros in Workbook
    CurrentWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, FileFormat:=56
        For SheetNumber = 1 To CurrentWB.Sheets.Count 'Counts Worksheets in Workbook
            CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select 'Selects All Worksheets in Workbook
            If (CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Name <> "What If") Then
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Unprotect ("UMC626") 'Unprotects Workbook
                Cells.Select  'Selects Data in Workbook
                With CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).UsedRange
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Protect Password:="UMC626", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True 'Protects Workbook
            End If
        Next SheetNumber 'Runs Through Iteration
        Sheets(1).Select
        Range("A1").Select 'Saves each workbook at the top of the page
        CurrentWB.SaveAs Filename:=SendTo & "\" & SendFile, FileFormat:=56, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False 'Saves Workbook in Flatten File Location
    CurrentWB.Close 'Closes Workbook

MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

**I solved the issue by using ThisName = CurrentWB.Name**

```
ALoopFile()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim SendTo As String
Dim SendFile As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook 'Workbook Stores Workbook

MyFolder = "Y:\Dropbox (Efficiency3)\Monthly Projects\001 - AU\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")

SendTo = "Y:\Dropbox (Efficiency3)\Monthly Projects\001 - AU\Flattened_Files"
SendFile = Dir(SendTo & "\*.xls")
Do While MyFile <> ""


Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=3) 'Sets CurrentWB = to that long name. This becomes the name of the workbook.
    CurrentWB.RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen 'Enables Macros in Workbook
    CurrentWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, FileFormat:=56
    ThisName = CurrentWB.Name
        For SheetNumber = 1 To CurrentWB.Sheets.Count 'Counts Worksheets in Workbook
            CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select 'Selects All Worksheets in Workbook
            If (CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Name <> "What If") Then
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Unprotect ("UMC626") 'Unprotects Workbook
                Cells.Select  'Selects Data in Workbook
                With CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).UsedRange
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Protect Password:="UMC626", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True 'Protects Workbook
            End If
        Next SheetNumber 'Runs Through Iteration
        Sheets(1).Select
        Range("A1").Select 'Saves each workbook at the top of the page
        CurrentWB.SaveAs Filename:=SendTo & "\" & ThisName
        CurrentWB.Close 'Closes Workbook

MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At first look, your target file doesn't have a name under `SendFile` variable.  You will probably want to use the same file name as `MyFile`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you run your code line by line, you will see `SendFile` has no value (blank name) so there is no such file can be output at the end.

Comment: Also, I don't think you are reading this right, `CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select 'Selects All Worksheets in Workbook`. It will not select all worksheets but will select the sheet at index `SheetNumber`.

Comment: I think I'm still confused by your use of `flatten`. Do you want **all** data in one Workbook or jam everything into one sheet for each Workbook?

Comment: I want to get rid of all of the formulas in the sheet, but keep the work books the same.

Comment: ian0411 how would I fix the sendfile issue?

Comment: You probably can check this one (https://superuser.com/questions/579170/how-to-save-the-excel-sheet-without-formula-and-macros) that will help you to save your Excel without formulas.

Comment: Also, if you want to have two variables, you can use `SendFile = MyFile` or just replace `SendFile` with `MyFile`.